# Php , jQuery and html combined

Tags: php, jquery, image, hosting, lightbox

```
  <script>
    $(".boxer").boxer({
        formatter: formatCaptions
        }); 
    function formatCaptions($target) {
        return '<p><span></span><?php the_field('price')?>' + $target.attr("title") + '</p>';
    }
  </script>
```

I'm using a jQuery lightbox. The fact is that in the localhost it worked well, but now that i'm online it doesn't show what i need. The site is [www.automediarent.it](http://www.automediarent.it/) ( go to page "Autoveicoli" under "Le mie Auto" )
 I hope that someone could help me. The lightbox is the one from Formstone

Comment: When I view your Source, I see: `function formatCaptions($target){return'<p><span>Cilindrata:</span>'+''+$target.attr("title")+'?></p>'` This suggests there is some failed PHP code trailing in there. Suggest `<?php echo the_field('price'); ?>`

Comment: I can't really tell from your question what the actual problem is? What is it that specifically that is not working any more?

Comment: I'm sorry Ishas it's my fault that I don't have explained correctly the problem.
I want to get custom fields to show the price,engine size, km/h ,horsepower,ecc.
The fact is that my implementation worked in the localhost but now that I'm online it doesn't.

Comment: I have fix it.
The problem wasn't there , i have cancelled this  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?> before the call of the footer , now it works!

Answer (score 0):

You do not appear to be printing the result of your PHP Function. Try this:

```
  <script>
    $(".boxer").boxer({
        formatter: formatCaptions
    }); 
    function formatCaptions($target) {
        return '<p><span></span><?php echo the_field('price'); ?>' + $target.attr("title") + '</p>';
    }
  </script>
```